# How to POST data with nsIWebBrowserPersist?

Tags: firefox-addon

I need to download the file (`saveURI`) with `nsIWebBrowserPersist` usage. But the file should be requested as POST. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code (thanks to BenB from IRC #extdev):

```
    var dataString = "name1=data1&name2=data2";  
    var stringStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].  
                       createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStringInputStream);  
    if ("data" in stringStream) // Gecko 1.9 or newer  
      stringStream.data = dataString;  
    else // 1.8 or older  
      stringStream.setData(dataString, dataString.length);  

    var postData = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/mime-input-stream;1"].  
                   createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMIMEInputStream);  
    postData.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
    postData.addContentLength = true;  
    postData.setData(stringStream);   

    persist.saveURI(fURI, null, aReferrer, postData, "", file);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Post_data_to_window#Preprocessing_POST_data

Answer (score 3):

`nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveURI()` takes an `aPostData` parameter - if you pass an input stream there a POST request will made. If you are sending some simple data, using [nsIStringInputStream](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/nsIStringStream.idl) should be easiest, something like this:

```js
var data = "a=1&b=2";
var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"]
                       .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStringInputStream);
stream.setData(data, data.length);
webBrowserPersist.saveURI(uri, null, null, stream, null, file);
```

Comment: Thanks, Wladimir. Actually I need to download the file with POST request, no additional data should be sent. But when I've tried to use your approach I see that 0 bytes file is downloaded and I don't see HTTP request with Wireshark...